# How to reset split screen to default in Notepad++

Tags: text-editor, notepad++

Using the compare plugin in Notepad++ splits the screen between the two files being compared. Is there a fast way to revert the screen to have all of the tabs again in a single window, as is the default view upon opening the application?

Comment: TLDR Its Ctrl + Alt + C for notepadd v7.6.3

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe this would be <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + d</kbd>.

To get to the split script use <kbd>Alt + d</kbd>.

See under `Plugins -> Compare`.

Comment: That command successfully closes the comparison nav bar, but the split screen divider persists.

Comment: I had an older version of notepad++ when I asked this question. Now that I upgraded, the command you described works perfectly! Thanks again.

Comment: This no longer works in NP++ v6.9. The two solutions below (dragging or right-clicking) do however.

Comment: @ChrisMueller - it does. You need the comparison plugin.

Answer (score 52):

Right click on the tab and the choose "Move to Other View"
This works for me on npp v6.6.9

Comment: I had to do this twice.  The first time stopped comparing.  The second time went back to the default view.

Answer (score 15):

You can drag all the files from one side to the other side. This will close the window that was left empty.

Comment: For me this is the best answer as I now understand the reasoning behind it. I had several files opened in the split screen. So compare->clear results didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will clear the comparison results.

*If the split screen remains after clearing the comparison results*, this is likely due to still having files open within each of the two split-screened-windows.

To resolve this, close the open files or move them from one of the two split screen windows to the other. Moving them can be done via drag and drop or by right-clicking on the file's tab and choosing 'move to other window". When the last file is moved or closed the split screen will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You used <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + x</kbd> and it does not help? Then try this if you use the **Document List Panel** (`Settings > Preferences > General > Document List Panel > [x] Show`) instead of the **Tab bar** (`Settings > Preferences > General > Tab bar > [x] Hide`), you should *move* all the files on the side with less files to the other view.

1. Find out which side has less files open by opening the Window menu once on both sides.
2. To move a file from one view to the other use `View > Move/Clone Current Document > Move to other view` or <kbd>Alt + v</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Still in split view? Switch focus back to the other side using <kbd>F8</kbd> and go to step 2.

Once all files on one side have been moved, the split view will disappear automatically.

PS. I know the question was about "tabs". However I regard the Document List as a better variant of "tabs".

Answer (score 1):

Under the plugins>Compare>Clear Results is where you will find a clickable menu option to do it aprt from the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

For "Clear Active Compare" - ctrl + Alt + X
For "Clear All Compares" - ctrl + Alt + Shift + X

Answer (score 1):

If you have disabled the **Tab bar** (`Settings | Preferences | General | Tab bar | [x] Hide`) and use **Document List / Switcher** (`Settings | Preferences | General | Document List Panel | [x] Show`), what you need to do is to first close all the documents open in the clone/split view. Once all files open in that have been closed, the split view will also close automatically.

Now, unfortunately there is no way(?) to tell what you have open in the split view and the main view. You'll just have to click on the right side split, and keep pressing `Ctrl` + `W` until the split view goes away. I guess you could also enable Tab bar for this occasion.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins--> Compare--> Clear Results

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow where answering questions is appreciated. However, repeating an existing answer is not very helpful, it just adds clutter to this site. Please look for other questions and, if you can, provide new answers.